# Sorting the mobile number with countrycode alone

Tags: java, android, sorting, for-loop, arraylist

I am having contact numbers listing screen. I stored those contacts in SQLite database and showing from that.

I need to filter mobile number which contains country code alone. When user saved same number with prefix "0" & without prefix "0". For example - +919876543211, 09876543211, 9876543211. I need to show only mobile number with country code when user saved like the example.

If user saved only mobile number need to show that alone or with prefix "0" means need to show that alone.

```
for(int i=0; i < arrayListContact.size()-1; i++){
   if(arrayListContact.get(i).getContact().startsWith("+")){
      plusArrayList.add(arrayListContact.get(i));
   } else if(arrayListContact.get(i).getContact().startsWith("0")){
      zeroArrayList.add(arrayListContact.get(i));
   } else {
      mobileArrayList.add(arrayListContact.get(i));
   }
}

 tempArrayList.addAll(plusArrayList);

for(int i=0; i < tempArrayList.size()-1; i++){
  String mobile = tempArrayList.get(i).getContact();
  String mobileWithout = getMobileNumberAlone(mobile);

for (int j = 0; j < zeroArrayList.size() - 1; j++) {
  if(!zeroArrayList.get(j).getContact().equals("0" + mobileWithout)){
     tempArrayList.add(zeroArrayList.get(j));
  }
}
}
```

I am passing tempArrayList to Adapter. But in below loop it is taking endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second loop, you're adding to the loop array so the loop never ends:

```
for(int i=0; i < tempArrayList.size()-1; i++)  // always uses latest array size
{
  String mobile = tempArrayList.get(i).getContact();
  String mobileWithout = getMobileNumberAlone(mobile);

  for (int j = 0; j < zeroArrayList.size() - 1; j++) 
  {
    if(!zeroArrayList.get(j).getContact().equals("0" + mobileWithout))
       { tempArrayList.add(zeroArrayList.get(j)); }  // adding to array, infinite loop
  }
}
```

Try this instead:

```
int tmplen = tempArrayList.size();  // starting size, never changes
for(int i=0; i < tmplen-1; i++)
......
```